# if try fails, except does not work - python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

```
def checker():
    try:
        ispresent = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpaths)                                                                                 #ispresent = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpaths) #works fine
    except:
        time.sleep(2)
        openlink()
    else:
         buyandlog()
```

if the xpath is present, then there are no problems, if I do use a link without the xpath, then the except won't run, no errors on the terminal are found; if I try to put a print("something") under the except, then it won't print anything nor in the output section under vscode, nor in the terminal

I fixed it

```
    ispresent = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "a-button-text.place.your-order-button").send_keys("webdriver" + Keys.ENTER)
```

adding .send_keys("webdriver" + Keys.ENTER) will raise the error, and then make the except work

Comment: We can't help unless you give us more to work with.  How is this function called?  What is the value of `xpaths`?  What is the current url?

Comment: Why do you think that `find_element` will raise an exception? Could it be that it just returns `None`, or an empty list? What does the documentation say?

Comment: @TurePålsson because their docs says that it will raise an exception https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/elements/finders/ for pretty much everything except via xpath

Comment: "If there are no matches, an empty list is returned." I don't seen anything in that link about an exception being raised.

Comment: Have you tried using `print(driver.find_element(...))` where you think it will raise an exception?

Comment: @chepner https://pastebin.com/KRr72E1i nothing, the terminal does not say anything nor it prints out anything, if I try with something else that's not a xpath like a class, or id, same results; also I'm really sorry the correct link of the docs is this https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html ; for the xpath it should not raise anything, while for everything else it should raise a NoSuchElementException

Comment: `find_element(...)` (singular) does raise accordingly; `find_elements(...)` plural would return an empty list;  Please update your question with a complete example.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

def checker():
    try:
        link = driver.find_element_by_xpath(linkAddress)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: adding from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException and except NoSuchElementException, didn't solve it, same issue

Comment: And change to : except NoSuchElementException: